# need to solve a question related to planes.

Tags: analytic-geometry, plane-geometry

I tried to solve the problem.  Here is the full question:

***Find the intercepts made by the plane (i)x - y+ z = 2.***

How to proceed forward? What is the first step in solving this problem? Can anyone guide me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: set in the equation two coordinates to $0$ and obtain the value of the third one.

Comment: useful! $(2,-2,2)$ right?

Comment: I would say that the intercepts are (2,0,0), (0,-2,0) and (0,0,2).